# Print the default red boxes around hyperref hyperlinks in my PDF after compilation

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

Owing to unsuccessful attempts after several searches on Internet, I hope to get some understanding *via* this forum on why the red boxes surrounding `hyperref` hyperlinks cannot be printed in my PDF output, and also know some way around (*if any*) to overcome this matter:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks = false
}

\title{\textbf{SampleDocFile}}
\date{{\small October 17\textsuperscript{th} 2016}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{First section}

\subsection{first subsection}
\subsubsection{first_first subsection}
\subsubsection{first_second subsection}
\subsection{first_third subsection}

\section{Second section}
\section{Third section} 

\end{document}
```

*Ps: I've noticed that most of the time users would like to get rid of the red frames /boxes, thus they're plenty of working solutions displayed on Internet. However I am keen on maintaining them after compilation in my PDF for some reasons, and look for best ways of achieving it.*

Thanks

**EDIT:**

As a way around, I am finally ending up with:

1.

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks = true
}
```

2. then I put a frame on my sections `(i.e \section{\frame{First section}})`

**Advantage:** Aim achieved within the table of contents (all being `framed` in red)

**Loophole:** Sections defined outside the table of contents are also framed. Thus, does someone know a way to break the dependency here, by keeping the frames only in the table of contents?

Comment: you can try `\section[\fbox{First section}]{First section}`

Comment: @touhami Cheers. The only shortcoming relative to the `samcarter` advocated approach, likewise in my edited answer, could be a `tedious`manual task if one has for instance hundred of sections involving _de facto_ a hundred of times manual insertion of `\fbox` in the doc.tex. I am not sure if there are ways to add `for loop` in `latex` to automate those commands. Will think of that... but thanks too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very hacky, but one could add a `\fcolorbox` in the definition of `\contentsline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
  }\x
  \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifcase\Hy@linktoc % none
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
    \or % section
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend} % HACK
      }{#3}%
    \or % page
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{{#2}}{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \else % all
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        }{}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        }{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{First section}

\subsection{first subsection}
\subsubsection{first first subsection}
\subsubsection{first second subsection}
\subsection{first third subsection}

\section{Second section}
\section{Third section} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or with tighter frames:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\cframe}[2]{%
    {\color{#1}\frame{\color{black}#2\color{#1}}}
}

\makeatletter
\def\contentsline#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
    \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\Hy@tocdestname{#4}%
  }\x
  \ifx\Hy@tocdestname\ltx@empty
    \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
  \else
    \ifcase\Hy@linktoc % none
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
    \or % section
      \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
        \cframe{red}{\hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend}
      }{#3}%
    \or % page
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{#3}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{{#2}}{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \else % all
      \def\Hy@temp{#3}%
      \ifx\Hy@temp\ltx@empty
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        }{}%
      \else
        \csname l@#1\endcsname{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend
        }{%
          \hyper@linkstart{link}{\Hy@tocdestname}{#3}\hyper@linkend
        }%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{First section}

\subsection{first subsection}
\subsubsection{first first subsection}
\subsubsection{first second subsection}
\subsection{first third subsection}

\section{Second section}
\section{Third section} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `Hacky` indeed (as you said), but `Very Ingenious` as working solution (most important). I am just impressed, so Many Thanks.

Comment: @dark.vador You're welcome! May I ask a nosy question? Why do you want the boxes in the toc to be printed?

Comment: `@samcarter:` sure. I was recently reading a technical documentation in `latex` and just found a bit `fancy` the printed red boxes displayed in the table of contents. Simple `curiousity` has lead me to investigate how this could be implemented by focusing on `\usepackage{hyperref}` including the different options available.  I therefore played a bit with the documented `colorlinks` option from `\hypersetup` until I had realized that my wish could not still be fullfilled. So this task starts becoming intellectually `challenging` until I post a thread as I have realized that I was stuck. Best